# Apt get install fails with errors

Tags: 14.04, apt

Whenever I install an application using sudo apt-get install application, I am getting the following error in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Even though I get the error, the installation of the applcation I try to install succeeds. How to I fix these errors?

```
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: line 81: gconf-schemas: command not found
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-common:
 libgnomevfs2-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-0:amd64:
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-common (>= 1:2.24); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-common (<< 1:2.25); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-common:
 libgnome2-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 isNo apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
            No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
     No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                   No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                            not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-0:amd64:
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-common (>= 2.32); however:
  Package libgnome2-common is not configured yet.
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-common (<< 2.33); however:
  Package libgnome2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbonoboui2-0:amd64:
 libbonoboui2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomeui-0:amd64:
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libbonoboui2-0 (>= 2.15.1); however:
  Package libbonoboui2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomeui-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up doc-base (0.10.5) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/doc-base.postinst: line 33: install-docs: command not found
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
           No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                         dpkg: error processing package doc-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome-vfs2.0-cil:
 libgnome-vfs2.0-cil depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome-vfs2.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2.24-cil:
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnome-vfs2.0-cil (= 2.24.2-3); however:
  Package libgnome-vfs2.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgnomeui-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2.24-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up mono-runtime-common (3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mono-runtime-common.postinst: line 4: update-binfmts: command not found
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
           dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pidgin:
 pidgin depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pidgin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Setting up xrdp (0.6.0-1) ...
adduser: The user `xrdp' already exists. Exiting.
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.2.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rabbitmq-server.postinst: line 59: update-rc.d: command not found
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up htop (1.0.3-1) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-bin:
 libgnome2-bin depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                              Processing triggers for menu (2.1.46ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 gconf2
 libgnomevfs2-common
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64
 libgnome2-common
 libgnome2-0:amd64
 libbonoboui2-0:amd64
 libgnomeui-0:amd64
 doc-base
 libgnome-vfs2.0-cil
 libgnome2.24-cil
 mono-runtime-common
 pidgin
 xrdp
 rabbitmq-server
 libgnome2-bin
```

Output of

> sudo dpkg --configure -a

```
$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
Setting up doc-base (0.10.5) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/doc-base.postinst: line 33: install-docs: command not found
dpkg: error processing package doc-base (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up mono-runtime-common (3.2.8+dfsg-4ubuntu1.1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mono-runtime-common.postinst: line 4: update-binfmts: command not found
dpkg: error processing package mono-runtime-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up xrdp (0.6.0-1) ...
adduser: The user `xrdp' already exists. Exiting.
dpkg: error processing package xrdp (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up rabbitmq-server (3.2.4-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/rabbitmq-server.postinst: line 59: update-rc.d: command not found
dpkg: error processing package rabbitmq-server (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
Setting up gconf2 (3.2.6-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: line 81: gconf-schemas: command not found
dpkg: error processing package gconf2 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 127
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-common:
 libgnomevfs2-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-common:
 libgnome2-common depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-common (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomevfs2-0:amd64:
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-common (>= 1:2.24); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-common (<< 1:2.25); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of pidgin:
 pidgin depends on gconf2 (>= 2.28.1-2); however:
  Package gconf2 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package pidgin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome-vfs2.0-cil:
 libgnome-vfs2.0-cil depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome-vfs2.0-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-0:amd64:
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-common (>= 2.32); however:
  Package libgnome2-common is not configured yet.
 libgnome2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-common (<< 2.33); however:
  Package libgnome2-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libbonoboui2-0:amd64:
 libbonoboui2-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libbonoboui2-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnomeui-0:amd64:
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libbonoboui2-0 (>= 2.15.1); however:
  Package libbonoboui2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnomeui-0:amd64 depends on libgnomevfs2-0 (>= 1:2.17.90); however:
  Package libgnomevfs2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnomeui-0:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2.24-cil:
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnome-vfs2.0-cil (= 2.24.2-3); however:
  Package libgnome-vfs2.0-cil is not configured yet.
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.
 libgnome2.24-cil depends on libgnomeui-0 (>= 2.22.0); however:
  Package libgnomeui-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2.24-cil (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libgnome2-bin:
 libgnome2-bin depends on libgnome2-0 (>= 2.17.3); however:
  Package libgnome2-0:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libgnome2-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 doc-base
 mono-runtime-common
 xrdp
 rabbitmq-server
 gconf2
 libgnomevfs2-common
 libgnome2-common
 libgnomevfs2-0:amd64
 pidgin
 libgnome-vfs2.0-cil
 libgnome2-0:amd64
 libbonoboui2-0:amd64
 libgnomeui-0:amd64
 libgnome2.24-cil
 libgnome2-bin
```

Comment: run command `apt-get -f install` then try to install these packages .  lets know your problem is resolved or not

Comment: configure un-configured packages by `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and try again.

Comment: `apt-get -f install` did not help. The output of `sudo dpkg --configure -a` is pasted in the question. Any clue what is happening?

Comment: the best option usually work is to reinstall those packages by one like this: `sudo apt-get remove --purge pidgin` and then `sudo apt-get install pidgin` you can firstly purge those unconfigured pkgs and then install them back by one...

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove xrdp
```

worked for me.

Comment: If he wants to install `xrdp` why should he remove it?

Answer (score 0):

> /var/lib/dpkg/info/gconf2.postinst: line 81: gconf-schemas: command not found

so lets see what package contains the missing ***gconf-schemas***

```
apt-file search gconf-schemas
```

shows us

```
gconf2: /usr/sbin/gconf-schemas           
gconf2: /usr/share/man/man8/gconf-schemas.8.gz
```

so just install it

```
sudo apt-get install gconf2
```